# Push readme to Github

Tags: eclipse, egit

I'm using:
Eclipse Kepler Build id: 20130606-0932
Egit version: 3.0.0.201306101825-r

I created a new repo on Github WITHOUT initializing it with a **readme.md** Then I cloned the repo with Egit. How do I create a readme.md locally and push it to Github so that Github can see it as a **.md** and display it accordingly?

Answer (score 3):

Just like any other file.

Create a file named `readme.md`, edit it, stage it, commit it, and push it.

Comment: Github won't see the readme.md file because it will be located inside the Eclipse project folder. I get a nag message from Github: "We recommend adding a README to this repository to help give people an overview of your project."

Comment: @mike: Add it to the _root_ of the repository; not inside the project folder.

Comment: You mean the "Working Directory" as shown in the Git "Repositories View" Yes, that works. Thank you.